# How can you test/measure muscular speed?

Tags: speed, measurements, progress

It's easy to see progress in a person's strength; they started at being able to bench x now they can bench x*2. The same is true for lots of strength exercises.

**What tests or measurements are there for muscle speed?**

I can think of some tests for muscle power which may be appropriate such as vertical jump, but I don't think it would be a good indicator of speed as strength is a large component of it.